# Evaluating $S_n= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right )^n dx$ for $n=3$ using $n=2,4$ and the Fourier transform

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

Given that $S_n= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right )^n dx$  one can deduce the value for $n=2$ by considering the function $f=1_{[-1,1]}$ and applying Plancherel's theorem. Similarly for $n=4$ one can consider the function $g=(1-|x|/2) 1_{[-2,2]}$.

But how can we, using the cases of $2$ and $4$ deduce the value of $S_3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Parseval-Plancheral theorem all the same:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\; \left (\frac{\sin{x}}{x} \right ) \, \left (\frac{\sin{x}}{x} \right )^2 = \frac1{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \, \pi 1_{[-1,1]} \; \pi \left (1-\frac{|k|}{2} \right ) 1_{[-2,2]}$$

Doing the integrals out and noting that the integration interval will be $[-1,1]$, we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\; \left (\frac{\sin{x}}{x} \right )^3 = \pi - \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{3 \pi}{4} $$

Comment: I have nothing against your solution, but it uses $n=1$ and $n=2$ (and not $n=2$ and $n=4$), which might be a typo of OP??

Comment: Well, I upvote, since I think this is how OP should calculate $S_3$.

Comment: @mickep: I think (and I should have pointed this out) that the OP seems confused about his labeling of $n$.

Comment: It seems that i have misread the problem and hence should have mentioned $n=1,2$ as @RonGordon rightfully has supposed to be the case.